# void*v[]; v[i] = v[j]; why this is right?

Tags: c

A `void*` is a pointer that points to nothing, i.e. it's only an address! How could one dereference it? But in the book *The C programming language (second edition)* page 121, the `swap` function seems to do it.

Comment: What? Please rephrase your question, it makes absolutely no sense!

Comment: Interesting question, but you should get someone to help you write it in clear English.

Comment: @Joe My english is poor,I don't know how

Comment: @ytyisme: I've edited your question, please have a look whether I got it right.

Comment: @DarkDust Thank you! It's right. How to open my question again?

Comment: You can't :-) Other people with higher reputation can vote to reopen it (which I just did).

Comment: @DarkDust Thank you! I want to know that we don't know how far between two void pointer how do know where it point to?

Answer (score 2):

`void *v[]` is an *array* of pointers. So `v[i] = v[j];` assigns an element at index `j` to the position `i` which does not involve dereferencing the pointer but merely copying the pointer(address).

Comment: Can you edit my questions become more clear?

Comment: `v[0]` is of type `void *`, not type `void`.

Comment: @PerJohansson oh,maybe,got it

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast the pointer into desired type. For instance, void* x; (int*)x - suddenly it's a pointer to int.